# For Each Loops in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, foreach

I'm just starting to learn AngularJS and I need to be able to create lists with a title and then items within it.

> **Category 1**
>   Item 1
>   Item 2
>   Etc
>   **Category 2**
>   Item 1
>   Item 2
>   Etc

How can I create a loop to get the category title, and then also get the items within that category?

In the code I would like to display it like this:

```
<h2>Category 1</h2>
<ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I'm sorry I can't give more information, I don't know enough about the language to provide more. Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I have tried:

```
$scope.categories = ['category 1', 'category 2']

<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    {{category}}
</div>
```

With this I dont know how to go another layer deep for the items.

Also I'm trying to do something like this (I don't know if it will work):

```
var categories = {$category: $items}

angular.forEach(categories, function(category, items)) {
     //Do Something
}
```

Comment: @Soviut Editied with some things I've tried, unfortunately not too helpful still

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you had a data structure like this; An array of categories, each category containing a `name` attribute and an `items` array containing all items belonging to that category.

```
$scope.categories = [
    {
        name: "Category1",
        items: [
            {name: "Item1"},
            {name: "Item2"},
            {name: "Item3"}
            // ...more items
        ]
    }
    // ...more categories
];
```

You could represent this in your template using [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) loops by looping over the `categories` array and inside each loop, perform a nested a loop over the `items` array in that category:

```
<div class="category" ng-repeat="category in categories">
  <h2>{{ category.name }}</h2>
  <ul class="items" ng-repeat="item in category.items">
    <li>{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-repeat. Here is an example:

Javascript:

```
var sections = {[
    {
        header: "Header1",
        content: ["one", "two", "three"]
    },
    {
        header: "Header2",
        content: ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
]};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="section in sections">
    <h2>{{section.header}}</h2>   
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in section.content">
            "Item: " {{item}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Make sure sections is a variable in the $scope of the controller this HTML is part of.